# TFS 2013- Cloning Team Projects

Tags: cloning, team-project

I am trying to clone a Team Project so I can have a test project that I can experiment on to help improve the Team Project without damaging the one we are currently using.

However, experiencing difficulties when researching how to do it.

Can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: Obviously couldn't clone the data so experimented with the live system which was actually ok. Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually clone a Team Project. If you want to experiment within the same Team Project Collection, you can best create a new Team Project and use the same process template.

By using the witadmin command you can export all work item definitions and process configuration and import them back in your new project.

If you have another server you can copy the databases and restore them on another server. You need to run TFSConfig /changeserverid to make sure you don't get caching problems.

Hope this helps